# Entware Package Manager (ipkg) Installation via .bin file

Tags: ipkg

`The goal is to install [Entware to a Generation-1 WD MyCloud NAS per instructions](https://community.wd.com/t/guide-nextcloud-on-wd-my-cloud/232018)

I was able to login to NAS command line and wget the Entware .bin file:

```
 wget https://github.com/WDCommunity/wdpksrc/releases/download/entware-v1.05/WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin
```

The instructions indicate: "install it with the WD web interface" however, I have traversed the Web UI and found only the update mechanism was for the firmware:

[image]

## What are the BASH commands required to install the.bin to enable `ipkg`?

I did find this `install` command in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/993635/545291):

```
NAS4TB:/opt/bin# cd /root
NAS4TB:~# ls
WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin
NAS4TB:~# 
NAS4TB:~# sudo install ./WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin
```

This returned an error:

```
NAS4TB:~# sudo install ./WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin
install: missing destination file operand after `./WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin'
Try `install --help' for more information.
```

I am reluctant to execute the `install` command without a better understanding the `install` command without guidance from experienced peer.

Comment: `install` is just a glorified `cp` and it's not what you think it is. Notice that the instructions say `opkg install...` not `sudo install...`. You don't need to use sudo as you're already a privileged user

Answer (score 0):

The instructions that you've [linked](https://community.wd.com/t/guide-nextcloud-on-wd-my-cloud/232018) say

> Get Entware from wdcommunity.com and install it with *the WD web interface*.

I've italicised the part you seem to have missed.

If you're worried about installing a package from a site you don't trust, consider reviewing installation options on the [Entware page itself](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki)

Comment: Thank you for response. It would seem that the WD web interface no longer has said installation capability.

Comment: Ah. Problematic. Have you tried `opkg install WDMyCloud_entware_1.05.bin`?

Comment: opkg is not found.  I realize now that the OP wrote `ipkg` when it should be opkg.  I tried the `install` command and updated the OP with the error returned.

Answer (score 0):

I used the web interface and installed from [here](https://github.com/WDCommunity/wdpksrc/releases/tag/entware-v1.05)

Comment: The original question says that it's not possible to install through the web interface. If you have successfully done so it would be worth explaining how